# Get all the Quickblox groups list from server

Tags: android, quickblox

I am using quickblox api 2.5.1 in android for chat,
**I want to get all the quickblox groups list which is available in quickblox server.**
Currently i am getting the list of groups which is created by me or which i am the member of that group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to get ALL group chats in your application because of permissions model.

Each user can request a list of chats he is in occupants list.

There is also public group chats type - these chats are available for every user in your app.

How to create Android Public Group Chat http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Create_a_Public_group_chat_dialog

Comment: Thanks Igor Khomenko